# Эмуляция прокрутки колеса мыши и нажатия клавиш в Selenium webdriver + node.js

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, тестирование, бот

Для определенного теста на странице сайта требуется выполнить прокрутку страницы.

Есть ли возможность эмулировать прокрутку колеса мыши?

И есть ли возможность эмулировать нажатия клавиш? Например "Page Down"

Использую стандартную библиотеку для node.js [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)

Comment: `element = driver.findElement(By.linkText(text)); driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", element);` . не рассматривали?

Comment: уже использую executeScript(), это "костыль", хочу узнать про встроенные возможности selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Selenium нет таких встроенных возможностей. Нужно понимать, что сам Selenium является некой оберткой над JS + Browser API. Всякие методы скролла, pageDown из под коробки не доступны. И Вам нунжно будет их описать самому. По этой причине появляются фреймворки поверх Selenium как EPAM JDI, Selenid и т.п.